# Get Windows installer error message programatically

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a way to get the error messages from [Windows Installer Error Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-error-messages) in code? For example, the input is `1101` and the output will be `Could not open file stream: [2]. System error: [3]`. This is not an error returned by `GetLastError` so `FormatMessage` will not work. Having my own look up table is also not feasible because there are a lot of errors.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm not trying to signal an error to the MSI installer process. I'm trying to "read" msi log better. For example, if I have `MSI (c) (C0:6C) [22:17:24:953]: Note: 1: 1402` in msi log so I want to convert the error code into something more understandable.

Comment: OK, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Your program may not execute if the Installer failed.